# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null] in Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, jackson, spring-data

Here is my method inside which I have this error

```
private <T> Mono<CarbonResponse<T>> evaluateVersion(Key key, String facts, boolean showTestResults) {
   return mapper.readValue(result,  new TypeReference<CarbonResponse<T>>() {}); // error here
}
```

where is result is JSON string.

My CarbonResponse.java

```
public class CarbonResponse<T> {
    int code;
    String message;
    DataV1<T> data;
}
```

DataV1.java

```
public class DataV1<T> {

    @JsonProperty(value = "rule_set_id")
    String ruleSetId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "version_id")
    String ruleSetVersionId;

    T result;

    @JsonProperty(value = "rules_evaluation_response")
    List<T> rulesEvaluationResponse;
}
```

gradle

```
 implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.3'
 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
 implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.3'
```

Full Error Strace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1266)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1250)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:670)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3197)
    at com.pharmeasy.carbon.client.CarbonClient.lambda$evaluateVersion$0(CarbonClient.java:321)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329)
```

Can I please know what am I missing here?

I figured this `new TypeReference<CarbonResponse<T>>() {}` is giving out null when we have T in it but I am not able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just can use

```
Mono<CarbonResponse<Void>>
new TypeReference<CarbonResponse<Void>
```

Comment: Better explain the cause of this issue and then suggest the solution.